# Assessing model performance

Tags: time-series, self-study, data-visualization, model-evaluation, model-comparison

Suppose there are $n=100000$ locations. At each location,there are observations of dependent variable $Y$ for 30 years. That is, we have time series data and this data have $100000$ rows and $30$ columns. We developed a model, and want to assess how well our model performs. With our proposed model, we also estimated the $y$ values at each time point to see if these $y$ estimates are close to the true value. But it is difficult to compare each pair of estimated value and its corresponding true value for all these $n=100000$ locations (since there are $100000\times 30$ pairs  to compare. We have $100000\times 30$ observed $y$ values, and then we estimated those $100000\times 30$ observed $y$ values by our proposed model yielding $100000\times 30$ estimated $y$ values.). How can we assess how well our model performs? Is there visual and/or numerical method to assess the model performance?

Comment: `But it is difficult to compare each pair of estimated value and its corresponding true value` why? Which metrics are you using and why? What is your research question?

Comment: @user2974951 Since there are $100000\times 30$ pairs  to compare. We have $100000\times 30$ observed $y$ values, and then we estimated those $100000\times 30$ observed $y$ values by our proposed model yielding $100000\times 30$ estimated $y$ values.

Comment: But are you actually interested in comparing each of these $3e6$ points or are you interested in some average performance?

Comment: 3 million comparisons is not difficult for a modern computer.  Visualising it is

Comment: @user2974951 actually in the beginning, I thought to draw line where in X-axis, there will be time, and in y-axis,  dependent variable, $Y$. But then there will be 100000 lines for all those locations only for true data, and another 100000 lines for estimated values by our model. The graph won't be understandable this way at all. Although, every location needs attention to see the pattern in that location, is there a way to compare for every location? If not, how to check average performance?

Comment: These problems might be perplexing or they might be easily solved, depending on *how* you want to make the comparisons.  For instance, you could start with univariate marginal comparisons by summarizing the 100,000 pairs at each of the 30 time points and again by summarizing the results for each time series at each of the 100,000 locations.  One usually starts with high-level general summaries (means, extremes, amounts of variation, *etc.*) and then drills down to explore the details, *if necessary.*  Thus, writing a more specific and detailed post is more likely to garner useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more sophisticated ways to get at this, but I would start with a [hexbin plot](https://r-graph-gallery.com/100-high-density-scatterplot-with-binning.html) of predicted vs. observed, and overlay a 1:1 line and a regression line.

Comment: How to interpret that hexbin plot?

Comment: @user149054 Like you would interpret a scatterplot.

Comment: But what the color palettes imply?

Comment: @user149054 Colour variation indicates how many data points fall within the area covered by a hexagon.

Comment: If I have 100 true values and I estimate those 100 values by our model and draw a scatter plot of estimated vs true values, do we expect to see a positive relationship between them since we would like to see our model can correctly estimate those true values?

Comment: @user149054 I'm sorry, comments are not for extended follow-ups. Please post a new question if you have one.